# Updating a detached object using merge doesn't updates the database

Tags: hibernate

I want to update an object before being detached but although it seems to be updated the database is not updated. Maybe the best way is to put what I am trying to acomplish.

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Object entity1 = (Object) session.get(Object.class, 1);        
session.close();

//I think this is where the problems lies as the Object I want to merge is quite      //complex

ObjectChild entitychild = entity1.getEntityChild();
entitychild.setData("data") ;

Session newSession = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction transaction = newSession.beginTransaction();        
Object mergedEntity = (Object) newSession.merge(entity1); 
transaction.commit(); //will cause an update to occur here
newSession.close();
```

When I try to retrieve the value from the nergedEntityObject I get the correct value:

```
ObjectChild entitychild = entity1.getEntityChild();
String updateData = entitychild.getData() ;
```

The value of updateData is "data" but this is not reflected on the database.

Is there anyway to approach this problem? I been looking and I don't know how to deal with the problem. I am new to hibernate but I have been struggling for two days with this. I was thinking of:

Trying to compare the differences between the first object and the detached object after applying the new values so I can merge the ObjectChild instead of the full Object. Is it possible?

Any other hints?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hibernate doesn't cascade `merge` by default. Have you annotated your entity to say something like `@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)`?

Comment: First of all many thanks for the anwer. I have used Eclipse to change the Default-cascade property of the ObjectChild.hbm.xml to true but I have got the same results :-(, is this annotation the same? Many thanks.

Comment: I've never used hbm files, but the documentation says `default-cascade` takes a string and sets defaults for *all* entities. It's unlikely you want that. Instead have the *parent* object say smth like `<many-to-one name="entityChild" column="child_id" cascade="merge" />`.